# Passing Mark or

Tags: word-choice

Lets suppose two students are talking to each other and one of them asks the other one:

> - Hey Andrew, do you know what is the passing... in the exam?

Is there a fixed term in American English or all the listed terms bellow mean the same:

> - Passing mark
> - Passing grade
> - Passing score
> - Passing point

Comment: Please provide additional context, all your phrases may have slightly different meanings depending on how they are used.

Comment: @ColleenV they are absolutely different matters at least depending on my mother language and this is why I brought it up as a new thread here.

Comment: There *is* a difference in usage between "passing mark" and "take a mark off", but in both cases your question is the same thing: "What is the correct usage of these four words?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [score](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/score)
>   : the number of points that someone gets for correct answers on a test, exam, etc.

This choice is most natural to me. Though it depends on the scoring/grading system you use. I am familiar with the A, B, C, D, F system, where A is (basically) excellent and F is failing. I would refer to these as grades. A grade of C or better is usually understood or accepted to be "passing".

So Andrew and I would understand that C or better is passing. Hence we would not ask this. Instead, we would ask

> Do you know what is the passing score was on the exam?

(I would use "on" not "in".) But again, this is probably based on the grading system you use. I am used to grades being curved, so a "passing score" can differ from exam to exam. One time, maybe a 70/100 is passing; another, it could be 50/100. If your scoring system is fixed, and the passing score does not change, then it would not make sense to ask "What was the passing score?"

It seems possible to interchange "mark" and "score", but personally, "mark" sounds like "grade" rather than "score". "Passing point" doesn't really sound academic to me. It sounds more like a physical landmark/threshold.